# Capturing PHP value in session or cookie

Tags: php, ajax, session, cookies, session-cookies

I am trying to capture the value of PHP output into a session or cookie so I can call it in other pages.  Please see example below

session-page1.php

```
<?php
session_start(); 
ob_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--
Strongly Typed 1.1 by HTML5 UP
html5up.net | @n33co
Free for personal and commercial use under the CCA 3.0 license (html5up.net/license)
-->

<html lang="en" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<?php $servurl = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>
<?php include_once "includes/ghead.php" ?>
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork" class="upload">

HEAD AND HEADER HTML CODE GOES HERE

<?php
 $fpath="upload/myImage.jpg";
 $size = getimagesize("$fpath");
 $nheight = $size[1];
 $nwidth = $size[0];

// Setting sessions
  $_SESSION['filepath'] = $fpath;
  $_SESSION['nwidth'] = $nwidth;
  $_SESSION['nheight'] = $nheight;

session_write_close(); 
?>
<header>   
  <h2><?php echo $fpath; ?></h2>
 <br> some html code goes here
 <br> <a href='session-page2.php'>go to page 2</a>
</header>
<?php echo $_SESSION['filepath']; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to now get the session values in page 2.

session-page2.php

```
<?php
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['filepath'].": ".$_SESSION['nwidth']."x".$_SESSION['nheight'];
session_write_close();
?>
```

The issue is that page1.php is not generating the session.  I tried the same thing using cookies and I am not having any luck either.

cookie-page1.php

```
<?php
 ob_start();
 session_start(); 

 $fpath="upload/myImage.jpg";
 $size = getimagesize("$fpath");
 $nheight = $size[1];
 $nwidth = $size[0];

// Setting cookies
  $cookie_name = 'test_cookie';
  $cookie_value = $fpath;
  setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (3600), '/'); // 1 hour (60 minutes * 60 seconds = 3,600 seconds)

  $cookie_name2 = 'test_cookie2';
  $cookie_value2 = $nwidth;
  setcookie($cookie_name2, $cookie_value2, time() + (3600), '/'); // 1 hour (60 minutes * 60 seconds = 3,600 seconds)

  $cookie_name3 = 'test_cookie3';
  $cookie_value3 = $nheight;
  setcookie($cookie_name3, $cookie_value3, time() + (3600), '/'); // 1 hour (60 minutes * 60 seconds = 3,600 seconds)

session_write_close(); 
ob_end_clean();
?>
```

I want to now get the cookie values in page 2.

```
<?php
 ob_start();
 session_start(); 

echo $_COOKIE['test_cookie1'].": ".$_COOKIE['test_cookie2']."x".$_COOKIE['test_cookie3'];

session_write_close(); 
ob_end_clean();
?>
```

The cookie is not generated and the value is not saved.  Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?  The code looks ok and should save the value/output of height/width and filename.  Also, if this is not possible in PHP, should I be using Ajax to save the value? if yes, can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you all in advance for your help!

Comment: what ahappens if you remove session_write_close(); 
ob_end_clean();

Comment: Hi Medda86 - The session nor cookie is getting generated and the value is not saved.

Comment: if you put echo $_SESSION['filepath']; in the end of page1.php you get anything? You are not requesting anything else before page1.php?

Comment: If I put $_SESSION['filepath']; in the end of page1.php I get "upload/myImage.jpg" I made edits to the code with other variables on page1.php

Comment: I edited the code for session_page1.php to give a better view.  But the code is the same for both session and cookie.

Comment: I never used session_write_close() so I dont know what that one does, but if it doesnt work, maybe you need to configure something with the php. Maybe google session with the software you using to run php.

Answer (score 0):

Test this one, if it's not working there's something wrong with your php installation or configuration. When you click refresh the session value should increase with +1

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['test']))
{
    $_SESSION['test'] = $_SESSION['test'] + 1;
}
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['test'] = 1;
    }
        echo 'Session value = '.$_SESSION['test'].'<br /><a href="">Refresh</a>';
?>
```

Comment: This increases with +1 every time I click on refresh.

Comment: I am wondering if the cookie or session is trying to set before PHP processes the image size.

Comment: well, your session works, but you need to run session_start() only one time. So if you have many files you inlcude, make sure only the first one has session_start()... You could make a separate file where you start the session and then run require_once('startsessionscript.php');

Comment: Hi Medda86, I couldn't vote up.  But wanted to say thank you. I loaded session_start in my global header script and it worked beautifully.  Thanks again!!! You Rock!!!